Is it possible to pass std::cin to a function wanting an iostream?
I am using a library that has a function taking an iostream for a data stream, but I want to pass std::cin. It apparently is not possible to pass an istream to an iostream, but is there way around this? Some way to create an iostream from stdin (eg re-opening stdin)?

That makes no sense. What if someone would call operator << or put() on std::cin that you passed?

That is not going to happen (at least that would not make sense given the library function in question).

Why would you want to do that? You can read into a string, construct an std::istringstream from it and use that. But that's still input only

If the function argument is iostream it means that the function is supposed to call both input and output operations on that argument, so clearly you cannot give it an object that doesn't support output operations. What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve? Do you need some "mocked" iostream that uses std::cin on input and some no-op on output?

You can certainly pass it as an std::istream  (input, but not output). It is not compatible w std::ostream or std::iostream.

There might be a way to rebind underlying stream buffer using rdbuf(), but honestly, if a library wants std::iostream and then proceeds to only use it as std::istream, then you should patch the library yourself instead of working around it.

As a quick fix, copy the std::istream into a std::stringstream, and then pass the std::stringstream into the library function.

I agree you should treat this as a bug in the library.  All of the major compilers do seem to behave sanely if you wrap std::cins stream buffer in a std::iostream though, as long as you don't try to write to the stream: https://godbolt.org/z/E4aEzfdvj.
